# How to remove or modify header from istio ingress gateway

Tags: istio

Chrome browser redirects all my domain and subdomain requests to HTTPS, this is unwanted behavior in my case.
according to https://www.chromium.org/hsts, this is HSTS policy that been added to chrome browser to the domain and all subdomains.

I am using Istio version 1.7.4 and noticed that the Istio ingress gateway add the header strict-transport-security that causes this issue.

```
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
```

how can I remove this header from the ingress gateway?

Comment: Hello, please try to use the `.headers.reponse.remove` within the `VirtualService` of your setup. More can be found here (like example): https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/?_ga=2.217871957.277552918.1614002881-1707490059.1584431549#Headers . Please tell if it solved your question.

Comment: yes, it solved it, thank you! do you think that I can change the value somehow? @DawidKruk you can add your comment as an answer here

Comment: Glad to hear it. When it comes to the operations on the headers please take a look on this: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Headers-HeaderOperations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `VirtualService` to add or remove certain headers.

The example from the official `Istio` documentation shows the way how you can remove it:

> #### Headers
>
> Message headers can be manipulated when `Envoy` forwards requests to, or responses from, a destination service. Header manipulation rules can be specified for a specific route destination or for all destinations. The following `VirtualService` adds a test header with the value true to requests that are routed to any reviews service destination. It also removes the `foo` response header, but only from responses coming from the `v1` subset (version) of the reviews service.
>
> - `v1alpha3`
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
> kind: VirtualService
> metadata:
>   name: reviews-route
> spec:
>   hosts:
>   - reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
>   http:
>   - headers:
>       request:
>         set:
>           test: true
>     route:
>     - destination:
>         host: reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
>         subset: v2
>       weight: 25
>     - destination:
>         host: reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
>         subset: v1
>       headers:
>         response:
>           remove:
>           - foo # <-- HERE!
>       weight: 75
> ```
>
> - *[Istio.io: Latest: Docs: Reference: Config: Networking: Virtual service: Headers](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Headers)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Istio.io: Latest: Docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/)*